# react-rails asset pipeline image path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, asset-pipeline, react-rails

I'm using the [react-rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) gem, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to load images from the asset pipeline.

I handle this currently by using the `.js.jsx.erb` extension, but as far as I know this is unconventional. (am I correct?)

Sometimes I just use an empty div and and set the div's `background-image` property as the image I intend to use.

What is the best way to go about loading images to react components when using `react-rails`?

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways to import image...

1) If you are direct using `jsx.erb` or `js.erb` file...

```
var image_path = "<%= asset_path(my_image.png) %>"

                        OR

render: function() {
 return (
  <img src={"<%= asset_url('path/to/image.png') %>"} />
 )
}
```

2) Passing as props Through `.erb` file to `.js.erb` or `.jsx.erb` file

in your `.erb` file

```
render_component('Component', img_src: image_url('the_path'))
```

in your `.js.erb` or `.jsx.erb` file

```
render: function() {
 return (
  <img src={this.props.img_src} />
 )
}
```

3) Recommended: Use `.js` and `.jsx` file and render it using view file `.html.erb`

In view file `example.html.erb`

```
<%= react_component("Example", props: {}, prerender: false) %>
```

In `.jsx` file `Example.jsx`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Image from "<IMAGE_PATH>/image.png";

export default class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props, _railsContext) {
   super(props);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
       <img src={Image} alt="example" />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

You need to register `Example` component. In your `app > javascript > packs > application.js`

```
import ReactOnRails from "react-on-rails";
import Exmaple from "<COMPONENT_PATH>/Exmaple";

ReactOnRails.register({
 Exmaple
});
```

Source: [github](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/issues/211)

Comment: I've tried both ways. Currently I'm doing it the first way, but it seems like most people do not use `jsx.erb`. The second way is problematic because sometimes I have to pass the images several levels.

Comment: I do know how to get it to work. I want to know what the "best practice" is.

Comment: I think 3rd way might help you. I used react-on-rails, you can use react-rails accordingly.

Comment: It is not specified in the readme but I tried jsx.erb and it works with react-rails@2.6.1